# Pivoting on a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I have this df

```
id   w1  w2   w3   w4
123  abc eat drink blabla
123  fgh eat sleep sigh 
456  kit ty  old   young 
456  ty love abc   fly
```

I would liek to have a df where each word repeted only one is associated to its id, for example

```
id word 
123 abc 
123 eat
123 drink 
123 blabla 
123 fgh 
123 sleep 
123 sigh
456 kit
456 ty
456 old 
456 young ù
456 love 
456 abc 
456 fly
```

I was looking to pivot_longer function but I didn't successed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_longer(-id, values_to = 'word') %>% select(-name) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 14 x 2
      id word  
   <dbl> <chr> 
 1   123 abc   
 2   123 eat   
 3   123 drink 
 4   123 blabla
 5   123 fgh   
 6   123 sleep 
 7   123 sigh  
 8   456 kit   
 9   456 ty    
10   456 old   
11   456 young 
12   456 love  
13   456 abc   
14   456 fly
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame (id = c(123,123,456), w1= c("abc","fgh","kit"), w2 =c("eat","eat","ty"))
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols =c("w1","w2") )
```

```
     id name  value
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1   123 w1    abc  
2   123 w2    eat  
3   123 w1    fgh  
4   123 w2    eat  
5   456 w1    kit  
6   456 w2    ty
```